# A method for automatically generating JButtons?

Tags: java, swing, methods, jbutton

I am currently a java newbie of sorts writing a program that is, essentially, a board game, almost identical to checkers. Unfortunately, this also means I need one hundred JButtons for the checkerboard. I know there is a way to have automatically generated JButtons, I've seen it done. I have no idea how I would go about this, though. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: A loop? For instance, `List<JButton> jbuttons = new ...; for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++) jbuttons.add (new JButton ...);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to generate a board game, you should use a `GridLayout` which will help you a lot positioning your buttons with minimal effort. Something like this:

```
public JPanel createBoardGame()
    JPanel boardGame = new JPanel(new GridLayout(numberOfRows,numberOfColumns));
    for (int i=0; i<numberOfRows*numberOfColumns; i++) {
        boardGame.add(new JButton(""));
    }
}
```

Here is a nice [article](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/buttons) that should help you a lot implementing your needs.